# What is 1. in Math or numpy? Is it supposed to mean 1.0?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, math

```
A = np.array([[1, -2, 1], [2, 1, -3], [1, -3, 3]])
b = np.array([6, -3, 10])
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
print(x) 
#[ 1. -2.  1.]
```

What format is this? This is my first time seeing it. how does it translate to normal numbers?

Comment: Yes, 1. is the same as 1.0, an integer that is stored as a float.

Comment: `np.array([1,-2,1], dtype=float)` should print the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number `1.` is a shorter way of writing `1.0`, and indicates that we are not dealing with an integer, but rather a floating point number. Consider following outputs:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(np.array([1,-2,1], dtype=float)) 
[ 1. -2.  1.]
>>> print(np.array([1,-2,1], dtype=int))
[ 1 -2  1]
>>> print(np.array([1,-2,1], dtype=np.float32))
[ 1. -2.  1.]
>>> print(np.array([1,-2,1], dtype=np.float16))
[ 1. -2.  1.]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I can not upvote because I do not have  enough  "reputation" hahaha

Comment: Sure, please consider accepting the answer if it explained your question.